# Print history list with ocaml utop

Tags: ocaml, utop

Is there a way to print the history list in utop, like calling `history` from bash?  I haven't found any sort of history ring associated with `utop-mode` in emacs either.  I'm trying to use the history to hippie-expand against in the REPL.

Utop appears to respond to commands like `history-prev` and `history-next` (from `utop.el`), but that is all I have found.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This

```
μ> #require "lambda-term";;
μ> LTerm_history.contents UTop.history;;
```

will print out your `utop` history as an OCaml list of strings with the first element being the latest command you've executed (which is unsurprisingly
 `"LTerm_history.contents UTop.history;;"`).

Note: you can add `#require "lambda-term";;` into your `.ocamlinit` file to skip the first command in the above listing.

There is also `~/.utop-history` file, if you'd like to use some system utilities to access your `utop` history.